# Not able to flush the haselcast cache once it reaches configured number of entries/size

Tags: caching, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

Wanted to clear the hazelcast cache. So that once cache reaches Max Entries or Max Heap Size, flush it into a file.

configuration in hazelcast.xml

```
<map name="TEST_CACHE">
    <max-size policy="PER_NODE">3</max-size>
    <eviction-policy>LFU</eviction-policy> 
</map>
```

Test code

```
public class Test implements EntryEvictedListener , Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1927328346902661527L;
    private static HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance = HazelCacheUtil
            .getHazelCacheInstance();
    private static volatile IMap<Object, Object> hazel_cache = hazelcastInstance
            .getMap("TEST_CACHE");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        hazel_cache.addEntryListener(new Test(),true);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            hazel_cache.put(i+1, new Test());
        }
        System.out.println(hazel_cache);

        System.out.println("");
        for (Entry e : hazel_cache.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(e.getKey() + " : " + e.getValue());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void entryEvicted(EntryEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getKey()+" : "+e.getOldValue()+"\n");
    }
}
```

and in entryEvicted i'm only getting the 3rd entry object

```
 Entry EVICTED :: 1
3 : com.test.CAO.Test@5a6b6126
```

is there any way to flush the cache content into a file/db once max-size is reached ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an evictionPercentage in map config. This percentage of entries are evicted when max size is reached.

Also note that hazelcast is designed for big number of entries and evictions are done per partition. So I recommend you to do your tests with 1000+ entries to see expected results.